# How edit one item in main menu CSS WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress

I want to change the color to black. ow can I do this using CSS only?

I tried additional CSS but it's not changing in front end. How can I edit one item in main menu?

[image]

```
<li id="menu-item-1075" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1075">
  <a href="style="
background: #b19540;
border-bottom-left-radius:20px;
">Get Directions</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Your CSS shouldn't have `element .style` in it, and there should be a dot ahead of `menu-item-type-custom...`, but I'm not sure what you're showing us there. You should probably do some reading on the basics of CSS so you understand the syntax.